# Haskell Listing Directories in Working Directory

Tags: beginner, haskell, file-system

I've got this fairly simple program to print out each subdirectory of the working dir.

```
import System.Directory (listDirectory, doesDirectoryExist)

main = do
    dirs <- getDirectories
    mapM_ putStrLn dirs

-- Get a list of directories within the working directory
getDirectories :: IO [FilePath]
getDirectories = do
    contents <- listDirectory "." 
    fIO doesDirectoryExist contents

-- Filter a list with an IO predicate.
-- (In this use case, queries file system for directory status.)
fIO :: (a -> IO Bool) -> [a] -> IO [a] 
fIO f [] = return []
fIO f (x:xs) = do
    matches <- f x 
    rest <- fIO f xs
    return $ (if matches then [x] else []) ++ rest
```

I also attempted this implementation of the `fIO` function, and I'm not sure if it's legitimately less clear or if it only appears that way to me because I'm not used to reading Haskell-style syntax yet.

```
fIO f (x:xs) = do
    matches <- f x 
    fIO f xs >>= return . ((if matches then [x] else []) ++)
```

#### Critique Request

Being a Haskell newbie, I'm sure a professional would change some things about this implementation. I'm curious what sticks out as awkward, non-idiomatic, or opaque. I'm also curious which implementation of the two `fIO`s (if either) you would select, and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `fIO f xs >>= return . ((if matches then [x] else []) ++)`, you can use `<$>`:

```
([x | matches] ++) <$> fIO f xs
```

Applicative style would allow you to compress all this yet further:

```
fIO f (x:xs) = (\matches -> ([x | matches] ++)) <$> f xs <*> fIO f xs
```

But in the end:

```
fIO = filterM
```

Comment: Cool thank you! I hadn't encountered Applicative yet, and I like that `[x | matches]` syntax. Is there a name for it? I tried searching for "hasekll guard singleton or empty list" and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Look for list comprehension syntax.